# Getting a Random Key:Value pair, assign into two separate variables inside a user-define function, return the result, print result, do it again

Tags: python, random, key-value

I'm struggling to get a key-value pair and assign them to two variables inside a user-defined function. Here is what I have so far:

```
def get_question_answer():
    
return
questions_answers = {
    "There is nothing wrong in this sentence. True or False?": "False",
    "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?": "None",
    "Which is not an alias of Nicki Minaj: Roman Zolanski, Barbie, Ryu, or Megatron?": "Ryu",
    "Which anime was not released in the 2010s: Tokyo Ghoul, Naruto Shippuden, Demon Slayer, or My Hero Academia?": "Naruto Shippuden",
    "True or False: Since the Harry Potter movies, only 1 actor has died.": "False",
    "True or False: The height of Mount Everest is 29,032 ft.": "True",
    "True or False: Rocket League is a sequel to the game 'Supersonic Acrobatic Rocket-Powered Battle-Cars'.": "True",
    "True or False: 20th Century Fox is not a subsidiary of Walt Disney Studios.": "False",
    "Amazing Grace is a song that describes Grace's amazing accomplishment. True or False?": "False",
    "Machine Gun Kelly and Megan Thee Stallion are engaged. True or False?": "False",
    "CorpseHusband has an official face reveal. True or False?": "False",
    "Fur Elise was written for Beethoven's student Elizabeth. True or False?": "True",
    "Eminem had 12 albums released over his career. True or False?": "False",
    "Broadway's 'Spongebob: The Musical' was a success after opening night. True or False?": "True",
    "Lin Miranda wrote the music for Alexander Hamilton, In The Heights, Encanto, and Moana. True or False?": "True",
    "As of 2020, there are about 1,057,379 total words in the English language. True or False?": "True"}

print("Welcome to Mental Samurai!")
print("This shorter version of the TV show asks you 16 questions.")
print("Get a question wrong, and the game is over.")
print("Your answer should have the first letter capitalized, same for the second word if needed.")
print("Get ready to play!")
```

I want to keep getting a random question while deleting the questions already asked until the user answers a question wrong, which will then end the program.

I hope you understand my problem and help me with getting the correct output.

Comment: Please follow the rules of [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get good answers - here I am lacking any code (attempt) you wrote to solve this problem (no use of random, how to avoid reusing a question etc.). Your question is appearing to me - more as an externalized programming job, - and you did not yet study Python programming basics?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your question and answers in a dictionary called `qa` you can use the random module and choice function to chose keys at random, In code, that would look like

```py
import random
question = random.choice(list(qa.keys()))
answer = qa.pop(question)
```

Pop will return the value corresponding to they key (question) and remove that pair from your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could `shuffle` the keys and loop over them. You're assured to have each question only once until you decide to stop.

Here is an example of code logic, assuming `ask` asks the question:

```
import random

keys = list(questions_answers.keys())

random.shuffle(keys)

for key in keys:
    answer = ask(key)
    if answer != questions_answers[key]:
        break
```